# How do I set the columnwidth of XWPFTable in XWPFDocument in c#?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have tried the following,

```
XWPFTable table = doc.CreateTable();
table.Width = 4500;
table.SetColumnWidth(0, 100);
```

but could not find reflection of result for the code in the document.
I am facing this due to text wrapping inside the table cells.
e.g.,status(columnheader) wrapped to two lines.suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var table = doc.CreateTable(1, 3); 

        table.Width = 5500;

        // Set first column width
        var mPr1 = table.GetRow(0).GetCell(0).GetCTTc().AddNewTcPr();
        mPr1.tcW = new CT_TblWidth { w = "1300", type = ST_TblWidth.dxa };

        // Column 2 auto resizes

        // Set last column width
        var mPrLast = table.GetRow(0).GetCell(2).GetCTTc().AddNewTcPr();
        mPrLast.tcW = new CT_TblWidth { w = "700", type = ST_TblWidth.dxa };
```